# Scalar Kalman filter implementation

Tags: algorithm, kalman-filter

Trying to use the Kálmán filter to find the steady state of time series data.

Can see Kálmán algorithm as follows for a scalar:

Predict:

```
x(k|k-1) = Ax(k-1|k-1) + B U(k)
P(k|k-1) = AP(k-1|k-1) + W(k)
```

Update:

```
y(k) = c x(k) + v(k)
K(k) = P(k|k-1)C/(CP(k|k-1) + v(k)
P(k|k) = (1-K(k)C)P(k|k-1)
```

I am trying to understand the difference between P(k|k) and P(k|k-1).
When this is implemented, do P(k|k) becomes the P(k|k-1) in the next iteration? If yes, does the error covariance W(k) in P(k|k-1) is not included in calculations or are they different terms?

Comment: Can you please add to your question where you borrowed the notation from? (And please check the changes I made, especially K→k.) Your question may do better over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=K%C3%A1lm%C3%A1n+uncertainty+covariance). I find it difficult to parse and interpret the last question in your post - can you simplify it? (maybe *does `X` is not included in `Y`* should be *is `X` not included in `Y`*)

Comment: Got this from a set of course note on the web. was trying to understand how it works. I am  looks for more resources on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `prediction` and `update` steps in your example belong to the iteration `k`.

From the perspective of the iteration `k` you have following covariances:

`P(k-1|k-1)` - a posteriori covariance at iteration `k-1` (after the measurement processing)

`P(k|k-1)` - a priori covariance at iteration `k` (after the prediction step, before the measurement processing)

`P(k|k)` - a posteriori covariance at iteration `k` (after the measurement processing)

So the difference between `P(k|k)` and `P(k|k-1)` is that `P(k|k)` involves the information from the last measurement and `P(k|k-1)` does not.

Here is the same thing for two different iterations:

**iteration `k-1`:**

`P(k-1|k-2) = P(k-2|k-2) + W(k-1)`

`P(k-1|k-1) = (1-K(k-1))P(k-1|k-2)`

**iteration `k`:**

`P(k|k-1) = P(k-1|k-1) + W(k)`

`P(k|k) = (1-K(k))P(k|k-1)`

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. I would appreciate if you accept the answer. Thanks